# Garbage data while inserting data with special characters in SQL Server 2012 using Perl

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, perl, encode

I have an XML file with data in multiple languages (eg. - Russian, Japanese, Chinese, English). This XML is created on Linux platform and it has passed [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) checks.

Now, I am reading this data from XML file and inserting into SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7 platform (XML also present on Windows). But I am getting `????` as a value in fields. This is happening for some of the cases like all the sentence in other language.

But, if any sentence having some special characters it's working fine.

I am using function

```
$row_value = decode("utf-8",$row_value);
```

Comment: How do you process the XML files? What DBD driver do you use? How do you configure the connection?

Comment: Using PERL read function, opening files. my $dsn = "dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database";

Comment: How are you reading the XML file?

Comment: open(FH, <XML_FILE_NAME>);

Comment: Make sure the column you are pushing it into is Nvarchar not varchar.

Comment: The field was Nvarchar already. N'$variable_name' this worked. Adding N before variable in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Encode;
require Encode::Detect;
my $utf8 = decode("Detect", $data);
```

> Try this for decode data...

Comment: Convert it into utf8 as default